# Как разместить несколько сайтов на одном доменном имени в nginx?

Tags: nginx, веб-сервер, proxy, proxypass

Допустим есть домен "services.ru". Есть 2 или более сервисов (teamcity, gitea и тд).
Как настроить nginx так, чтобы при обращении к services.ru/teamcity открывался этот сервис?  При этом сам тимсити не должен знать что в uri есть "/teamcity/", т.е. пользователь видит "services.ru/teamcity/login.html" а сам сервис видит "services.ru/login.html". И вот такое нужно провернуть с ещё несколькими сервисами. Я так понял что нужно использовать регулярные выражения в конфиге и т.д., а одной директивы proxy_pass не достаточно.

Comment: «не должен знать что в uri есть» — с этим скорее всего будет проблематично, ведь сервисы станут генерировать сломанные ссылки на другие страницы. И если в html/css коде их ещё можно попытаться исправить регулярками в настройках nginx, то вот что делать с javascript-кодом — не очень понятно. Поэтому будет лучше, если сервисы будут знать про изменённый url и сами смогут генерировать правильные ссылки без костылей

Comment: В таком случае, можно ли настроить nginx так, чтобы сервис понимал "services.ru/teamcity" как своё доменное имя?

Comment: Во-первых, нельзя, а во-вторых, проблему с генерацией сломанных ссылок это всё равно не решило бы. // Не по теме вопроса, но чем не угодило teamcity.services.ru?

Comment: (но вообще, если гугл меня не обманывает, и teamcity, и gitea позволяют указать произвольный root url в своих конфигах, так что если есть возможность обновить их конфиг, то лучше обновить их конфиг)

Answer (score 0):

Используйте например

```
location ~* /teamcity(.*) {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://host:port$1;
}
```